# How to pass value to Facebook dialog on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm implementing Post message to Wall look like below by using Facebook dialog like below img
[image]

Anybody know how to pass the value from Activity to FB Dialog something like "Share your idea here..." and put it like a hint for the textbox on diablog? pls help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to put a text as message for the user, then the answer is that you can not do that.

In the past it was possible to add the "message" parameter but applications abused that option and so facebook decided to remove the option.
When using the dialog, the user has full control of what goes into the message field.

The only way (that I'm aware of) that you can do that is to ask for the "publish_stream" permission and then publish as the user without using the dialog, in an android context it's using the *[facebook.request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/)* (or [the async way](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/)), something like:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("link", "http://stackoverflow.com");
parameters.putString("message", "A user message..");
facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```